# React Proptypes gives error while generating Proptypes for a component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I am getting an error with PropTypes.
The Props are:

```
type FieldTypes = 'dropdown' | 'checkbox';

type PluginDropdownData = {
  label: string;
  value: string;
};

type PluginManifestObject = {
  label: string;
  type: FieldTypes;
  data: Array<PluginDropdownData> | Array<string>;
  mandatory: boolean;
};

{
  manifestObject: PluginManifestObject
  objectKey: string;
  handleValueChange: (label: string, value: string | boolean) => void;
  initialValue: string | boolean;
}
```

This is my solution:

```
 ComponentA.propTypes = {
  manifestObject: PropTypes.shape({
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    type: PropTypes.oneOf(['dropdown', 'checkbox']).isRequired,
    data: PropTypes.oneOfType([
      PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      })),
      PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
    ]).isRequired,
    mandatory: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,,
  objectKey: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  handleValueChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  initialValue: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.bool,
  ]).isRequired,
};
```

But I am getting 2 errors:

```
Type 'Validator<InferProps<{ label: Validator<string>; type: Validator<string>; data: Validator<(InferProps<{ label: Validator<string>; value: Validator<string>; }> | null | undefined)[] | (string | ... 1 more ... | undefined)[]>; mandatory: Validator<...>; }>>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<PluginManifestObject>'.
  Type 'InferProps<{ label: Validator<string>; type: Validator<string>; data: Validator<(InferProps<{ label: Validator<string>; value: Validator<string>; }> | null | undefined)[] | (string | ... 1 more ... | undefined)[]>; mandatory: Validator<...>; }>' is not assignable to type 'PluginManifestObject'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FieldTypes'.ts(2322)
(property) manifestObject?: React.Validator<PluginManifestObject> | undefined
```

The above error is fixed by aleksxor answer but there is still one error, i.e.

```
Type 'Validator<InferProps<{ label: Validator<string>; type: Validator<"input" | "dropdown" | "checkbox" | "date" | "radio" | "range">; data: Validator<(InferProps<{ label: Validator<string>; value: Validator<...>; }> | null | undefined)[] | (string | ... 1 more ... | undefined)[]>; mandatory: Validator<...>; }>>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<PluginManifestObject>'.
  Type 'InferProps<{ label: Validator<string>; type: Validator<"input" | "dropdown" | "checkbox" | "date" | "radio" | "range">; data: Validator<(InferProps<{ label: Validator<string>; value: Validator<...>; }> | null | undefined)[] | (string | ... 1 more ... | undefined)[]>; mandatory: Validator<...>; }>' is not assignable to type 'PluginManifestObject'.
    Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
      Type '(InferProps<{ label: Validator<string>; value: Validator<string>; }> | null | undefined)[] | (string | null | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[] | PluginDropdownData[]'.
        Type '(InferProps<{ label: Validator<string>; value: Validator<string>; }> | null | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[] | PluginDropdownData[]'.
          Type '(InferProps<{ label: Validator<string>; value: Validator<string>; }> | null | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
            Type 'InferProps<{ label: Validator<string>; value: Validator<string>; }> | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
              Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
(property) manifestObject?: React.Validator<PluginManifestObject> | undefined
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error, specifically? Please include that in your question.

Comment: The error is there in the image attached but I will add it as well

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're passing non-readonly array to the `oneOf` validator. And the values of non-readonly array are inferred as `string` type. The solution is pretty simple. Just pass it readonly tuple:

```ts
   ...
   type: PropTypes.oneOf(['dropdown', 'checkbox'] as const).isRequired,
   ...
```

---

Updated answer to address the second error.

To match the type: `data: Array<PluginDropdownData> | Array<string>` you have to define your propTypes as:

```ts
   ...
   data: PropTypes.oneOfType([
       PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
           label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
           value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
       }).isRequired),
       PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string.isRequired),
   ]).isRequired,
```

Notice that if you want the array to pass the validation you have to declare it's elements as `isRequired`. If you're not planning to make them `isRequired` you have to add  `| null | undefined` to array's item type. For example those two definitions pass without error:

```ts
type PluginManifestObject = {
   ...
   data: Array<PluginDropdownData | undefined | null> | Array<string | undefined | null>
   ...
}

   ...
   data: PropTypes.oneOfType([
      PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
          label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
          value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      })),
      PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
  ]).isRequired,
  ...
```

Comment: This solves the first error. I am getting another error after fixing the first one?